# TensorFlow MNIST example error - should I have to update?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am quite newbie in Tensorflow. My version is 0.10.0.

When running the code on 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

I have the following error:

> File "mnist_tf_example.py", line 163, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 30, in run
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>   File "mnist_tf_example.py", line 137, in main
>       logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoggingTensorHook'

should I have to update tensorflow? the version I installed is the one in the [Tensorflow's website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your installation is broken.

The current TensorFlow version, including the one you pointed to at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux is 1.1.0 and it seems you're using the MNIST example from the corresponding release branch (r1.1)

However, you mentioned that your TensorFlow version is 0.10.0.

You might need to uninstall/reinstall and validate that you have the correct version using something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print tf.__version__
```

And ensuring it is 1.1.0 or later.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are completely right. I really don't know what happened. I updated pip and updated tensorflow. However just by importing tensorflow I have an error stating that tensorflow cant find libcublas.so.8.0. So, maybe Tensorflow 1.1 only works with CUDA 8.0? can I make this last version working with CUDA 7.5?

Comment: You're right, the release binaries require CUDA 8 (see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux), for CUDA 7.5 you will have to build from source.